# Include Kafka and Zookeeper in Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, spotify

I need to make a Docker container for a project involving streaming data using Kafka and Zookeeper. Looking around I found [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/spotify/kafka/) docker image from Spotify, including Kafka and Zookeeper.

How should I include it in my project? Should I include in the Dockerfile the suggested commands, listed below?

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine active\`` --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka

export KAFKA=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine active\``:9092
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list $KAFKA --topic test

export ZOOKEEPER=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine active\``:2181
kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper $ZOOKEEPER --topic test
```

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by "including" Kafka & Zookeeper in your project. Either way - those are _shell_ commands (to start up your Dockerised Kafka & ZK), not Dockerfile instructions.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I need to live stream some data, and my plan is to do so using Kafka and Zookeeper. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to containerize Kafka and Zookeeper.

Comment: OK - well Spotify already containerised them, as per your link. You can _use_ their image by running the above `docker run` command, but how you do _this_ (other than just typing it in to a terminal) depends on what language / framework / project setup you're using...

Comment: The spotify image is heavily outdated. I wouldn't suggest it

Comment: @cricket_007 well spotted. I ended up using `wurstmeister/zookeeper` and `wurstmeister/kafka`

Comment: Yeah, those or the Confluent ones are updated more often. Confluent has enterprise support, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) file?

In your *.yaml you can set-up the services to pull the Kafka and Zookeeper images from Spotify's DockerHub, map ports (e.g. "2181:2181" and "9092:9092" for ZK and Kafka, respectively), set ENV variables, and persist data to a volume so you don't lose your topics and offsets.